# Photon Server not starting

Tags: c#, server, photon

I have the photon server up but when I start the load balancing the server starts for a few seconds then shuts down. I have shut down the firewalls, still not working. I am trying to use photon wire but when I press start it will not start.

Comment: can you take a look at the logs? log files locations are specified [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/onpremise/current/app-framework/logging#loglocations).

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Photon.CounterPublisher.SystemCounter' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry.
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)

Comment: this is what starts the shut down process

Comment: please take a look at this forum topic. it should help you in solution of your problem
http://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/33635/#Comment_33635